# How to iterate over files in a directory,do some operation and delete the file picked in each iteration so that it is not picked again?

Tags: unix

Here is what i am trying to do :

Import path = somepath

for f in somepath/somename_*.csv
do 
   someoperation
   rm f
done

The above piece of code gives error: 'rm' can not remove 'f' : no such file or directory.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `for f in somepath/somename_*.csv do someoperation; rm $f done` i believe.

in `rm` you need to use `f` as variable, so `$f` should be used.